# How to Retrieve subgrid values using plugin and store that retrieved column value as comma separated in normal text field

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I have sub grid called track and location in event entity. Now I want to retrieve the name of the sub grid values and store that values in the text field.[In pathway List field I need to add track name as comma separated if it is associate. If it is disassociate I need to remove the particular value form text field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgvUU.png).I am new to plugin. I tried query expression but I don't have any common filed for track and event entity to use filter condition. Can u any one suggest the way to achieve this quickly.
I tried below code:

```
if (context.MessageName.ToLower() == "associate")
        {
            // Obtain the target entity from the input parameters.
            Entity eventEntity = new Entity("leap_event");

            var pathwayList ="" ;

            QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("leap_event");

            query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true);

            LinkEntity linkEntity1 = new LinkEntity("leap_event", "leap_leap_event_leap_location", "leap_eventid", "leap_eventid", JoinOperator.Inner);

            LinkEntity linkEntity2 = new LinkEntity("leap_leap_event_leap_location", "leap_location", "leap_locationid", "leap_locationid", JoinOperator.Inner);

            linkEntity1.LinkEntities.Add(linkEntity2);

            query.LinkEntities.Add(linkEntity1);

            linkEntity2.LinkCriteria = new FilterExpression();

            linkEntity2.LinkCriteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("", ConditionOperator.Equal, ""));

            EntityCollection collRecords = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
            tracingService.Trace("load");
            for (int i = 0; i < collRecords.Entities.Count; i++)
            {
                tracingService.Trace("load1");
                var result = collRecords.Entities[i].GetAttributeValue<string>("leap_name"); 
                Console.WriteLine(result);
                pathwayList += result + ",";
                tracingService.Trace("pathwayName" + pathwayList);
                eventEntity["leap_pathwayList"] = pathwayList;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you will have to use alias for your linked Entity. Take a sample example below.

I have Account Entity--> (N:N) list member Entity--> (N:N) List Entity.

In your case it would be

leap_event Entity--> (N:N) leap_leap_event_leap_location Entity--> (most probably N:N or 1:N) leap_event_leap_location entity.

In addition when you retrieve attribute you will have to use `GetAttributeValue<AliasedValue>` Take a look at [this article](https://temmyraharjo.wordpress.com/2021/01/29/dynamics-crm-365-tips-easy-way-to-get-aliasedvalue/) it will help you understand

```
// Instantiate QueryExpression query
var query = new QueryExpression("account");


// Add columns to query.ColumnSet
query.ColumnSet.AddColumns("name", "accountid");

// Add link-entity listmemberentity
var listmemberentity = query.AddLink("listmember", "accountid", "entityid");
listmemberentity.EntityAlias = "listmemberentity";

// Add link-entity listentity
var listentity = listmemberentity.AddLink("list", "listid", "listid");
listentity.EntityAlias = "listentity";

// Add columns to listentity.Columns
listentity.Columns.AddColumns("listname");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to use linkentity.

The QueryExpression must be performed directly on the associated entity, with filter on lookup field (I assume "leap_eventid" field on "leap_location" entity) :

```
if (context.MessageName.ToLower() == "associate")
{
    var query = new QueryExpression("leap_location");
    query.ColumnSet.AddColumn("leap_name");
    // Lookup filter
    query.Criteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("leap_eventid", ConditionOperator.Equal, context.TargetEntity.Id));
    // Optional statecode filter 
    query.Criteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("statecode", ConditionOperator.Equal, 0));

    var collRecords = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
    if (collRecords.Entities.Count > 0)
    {
        var pathwayList = string.Empty;
        foreach (var location in collRecords.Entities)
        {
            pathwayList += location.GetAttributeValue<string>("leap_name") + ",";
            tracingService.Trace($"pathwayName {pathwayList}");
        }
    }
    var eventEntity = new Entity("leap_event", context.TargetEntity.Id)
    {
        ["leap_pathwayList"] = pathwayList
    };
    service.Update(eventEntity); // Update required for PostOperation Plugin
}
```